# How to Integrate a QR Code Generator and Scanner in VB.Net for Inventory Program?

Tags: .net, vb.net

For Example: I need to develop a Small Inventory program for nearby Super Market and the need is a QR Code should be Generated for the Model Number of a Product Eg: A for Iphone and then we scan the QR Code image by Scanner connected to the PC it should automatically fill the letter " A " in the input box so that i can use that for searching the product " Iphone "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method for doing this is to leverage an existing QR code library compatible with the .net framework. A quick search reveals an open source project [QRCode Library](http://platform.twit88.com/projects/mt-qrcode). The library supports both encoding and decoding qr codes. This should satisfy your condition of generating qr codes for Model Numbers and Product Numbers and then reading them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like on the "generate" side you might be able to use the TagLabs solution.  You can leverage the API to automatically create and manage QR Codes with the associated model number as needed.  Check out the developer site at developer.taglabsinc.com and create a free account at portal.taglabsinc.com.